# Что такое Пресет в Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel, jsx

Начал изучение Webpack, в статье автор устанавливает Babel, babel-core, babel-loader и.т.д затем объясняет что к чему, вот текст из статьи

"**babel-core:** Преобразует код ES6 в ES5.
**babel-loader:** Помощник Webpack для транспайлинга кода, задает пресеты.
**babel-preset-env:** Пресет, который помогает babel конвертировать код ES6, ES7 и ES8 в код ES5.
**babel-preset-react:** Пресет, преобразующий JSX в JavaScript."

Но я не понял что такое Пресеты или Пресет? что это и для чего это нужно?

Comment: `babel-preset` - относится к бабелю а не к вебпаку. Это просто набор настроек.